# CoreData could not fulfill a fault using encrypted-core-data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, encrypted-core-data-sql

I am using [encrypted-core-data](https://github.com/project-imas) to encrypt the data at rest. It works great, as long the app is not crashed or stopped manually. Application could not access the core data object after a failure and its throws below exception

> Jan 18 13:46:04 Test TestDemo[4504] : Name:
>   NSObjectInaccessibleException Jan 18 13:46:04 Test TestDemo[4504] :
>   Reason: CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x174026f00
>   x-coredata://96535FDB-865C-42B7-A1EE-ED80C705EC1D/TestSessionsCollection/p1'

As per below link, it looks like the object's underlying data has been deleted from the persistent store.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html

So for some reason, the data get lost/corrupted when the app is crashed/stopped. I am not sure whether I need to close/reset any context upon failure to prevent core data corruption.

As a recovery, reinitializing with new object is working fine.

Can someone let me know how to diagnose this issue?

Comment: You should chime in at https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data/issues/151 , to escalate the issue, it's probably a bug in the library

Comment: @andrew, Thanks. I have already reported this in that project. Trying to get more information from this forum as well.